# jquery if else statement not working

Tags: jquery, drupal, authentication

i have been trying different ways to make a div add itself when a toggle div is visible and remove when not. But the else is not read, no matter how i put it the else statement is never read.

this is what i have now

```
if ($('#toboggan-login').css('display') == 'none'){
    $("#art-main").append('<div class="outer-login"></div>');
} else{
    $("#art-main").find(".outer-login").removeClass();
}
```

i also have tried :visible and the counter :hidden but regardless of how it works if i cant get the else part of the statement to read i cant get the desired effect.

this is is drupal 6 website im working on

Comment: Is anything triggering this?

Comment: When are you running this, only on pageload ?

Comment: I think what you need is a working example to start with, the if else probably isn't the problem. Hope this helps ;) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qomAI

Comment: thanks, Shanimal. its running on document ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to connect this code with toggle event of '#toboggan-login'. Something like:

```
$('#toboggan-login').toggle('slow', function() {
  if ($(this).css('display') == 'none'){
    $("#art-main").append('<div class="outer-login"></div>');
  } else{
    $("#art-main").find(".outer-login").remove();
  }
});
```